# python namespace: __main__.Class not isinstance of package.Class

Tags: python, namespaces

Consider you have two python files as defined below. Say one is a general package (`class2`), and the other one does specific overrides and serves as the executable (`class1`).

class1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Test(object):
    pass

class Verificator():
    def check(self, myObject):
        if not isinstance( myObject, Test ):
            print "%s is no instance of %s" % (type(myObject),Test)
        else:
            print "OK!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from class2 import getTest

    v = Verificator()
    t = Test()
    v.check(t)
    s = getTest()
    v.check(s)
```

class2.py:

```
from class1 import Test
def getTest():
    return Test()
```

What happens is that the first check is OK, where the second fails. The reason is that `t` is `__main__.Test` whereas `s` is `class1.Test` and `v.check()` checks for `__main__.Test`, but at the end of the day it is the same class, right?

Is there a way to write `v.check()` such that it also accepts `class1.Test` objects, or any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

If you plan to import `class1.py` from elsewhere, move the top-level code (`if __name__ == '__main__': ...` to a separate file altogether. That way both the main file and `class2` work with the same `class1.Test` class.

Doing almost anything else opens a can of worms. While you can work around the immediate problem by switching `isinstance` to `type(myObject).__name__ == ...`, the fact remains that your Python process contains two `Test` classes where there should be only one. The otherwise indistinguishable classes know nothing of each other and fail each other's `issubclass` tests. This practically guarantees hard-to-diagnose bugs further down the line.

**EDIT** 
Another option is to explicitly import the classes from `class1` when executing as main, as in your answer. It would be advisable to go one step further and make sure that the classes aren't defined in double. For example, you can move the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block to the *beginning* of the file, and end it with `sys.exit(0)`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import class1, class2
    ... use only the public API with module prefixes ...
    sys.exit(0)

# the rest of the module follows here
```

Comment: This may be a clean solution, but I actually want to avoid splitting my scenario files in two.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hints, which finally helped me to experiment in the right direction. The solution I just found in this toy model, is to fix the namespace issue using an import. In order to rule out the issue user4815162342 pointed out, I added another class to class1. The following code for class1.py appears to do, what I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Test(object):
    pass

class Toast(object):
    pass

class Verificator():
    def check(self, myObject):
        if not isinstance( myObject, Test ):
            print "NOPE: %s is no instance of %s" % (type(myObject),Test)
        else:
            print "OK: %s is instance of %s" % (type(myObject),Test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from class2 import getTest
    from class1 import Test, Toast

    v = Verificator()
    t = Test()
    v.check(t)
    t = getTest()
    v.check(t)
    t = Toast()
    v.check(t)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `type()` function (you'll find this invocation fairly common, in fact!):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Test(object):
    pass

class Verificator():
    def check(self, myObject):
        if not isinstance( type(myObject), type(Test) ):
            print "%s is no instance of %s" % (type(myObject),Test)
        else:
            print "OK!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from class2 import getTest

    v = Verificator()
    t = Test()
    v.check(t)
    s = getTest()
    v.check(s)
```

The perhaps worse solution:

```
if not isinstance( myObject.__class__, Test.__class__ ):  # Use __class__ here.
```

They're of course equivalent, but it's considered bad form to need to use double-underscore members unless you desperately need to! It's worth knowing of their existence, though, hence why I've included this one in my answer.

Note that this happens, to the best of my knowledge, because when you run `python class1.py`, class1.py would have no module. As such, python places everything into the `__main__` module for you. This *isn't* the case when you import it from any other script, so seeing something as part of the `__main__` module is actually the special case!

Comment: I'd use `type(myObject)` instead. It comes down to the same thing but is using the official API, instead of reaching into the hook attribute directly.

Comment: Checking `isinstance(type(myObject), type(Test))` only tests that `myObject`'s type is created by `Test`'s metaclass. This will be true for any two new-style classes created by the default metaclass, and is almost certainly not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I triggered only on `__class__` there. Looking at it some more, I see that you only need test `isinstance(myObject, Test)`, no need to look up the type *at all*.

Comment: This answer is wrong (just like @user4815162342 already wrote), it is a known anti-pattern, see: [Using type() to compare types](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/do_not_compare_types_use_isinstance.html)