# Why do circular imports cause problems with object identity using `isinstance`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After a few hours of isolating a bug, I have come up with the following MCVE example to demonstrate the problem I've had:

a.py:

```
from b import get_foo_indirectly

class Foo:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Indirect:", isinstance(get_foo_indirectly(), Foo))
    print("Direct:", isinstance(Foo(), Foo))
```

b.py:

```
def get_foo_indirectly():
    from a import Foo
    return Foo()
```

The expected output of a.py is:

```
Indirect: True
Direct: True
```

The actual output is:

```
Indirect: False
Direct: True
```

Moreover, if I create a separate module c.py, the output is as expected:

```
from a import Foo
from b import get_foo_indirectly

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Indirect:", isinstance(get_foo_indirectly(), Foo))
    print("Direct:", isinstance(Foo(), Foo))
```

Clearly, the interaction between `isinstance` and the import machinery is not behaving quite like I expected it to. It seems like the use of circular imports has bitten me hard. Why? Is this Python's expected behavior?

Note that this is very oversimplified of the actual context in which I encountered this behavior; modules a and b were both large modules, and b was separated because it had a distinct purpose from a. Now that I've seen the consequences of circular imports, I will probably combine them, perhaps relegating some of the long-winded behavior in b.

Comment: @ehacinom Because of the nature of circular imports (though I clearly do not understand it completely); if you import `a` in `b` and `b` in `a` at the same time, you get an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_foo_indirectly' from 'b'`

Comment: If you print off `Foo()` in `a.py` you get `__main__.Foo instance`.

If you print off `Foo()` in `b.py` you get `a.Foo instance`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [python namespace: __main__.Class not isinstance of package.Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159854/python-namespace-main-class-not-isinstance-of-package-class)

Comment: @John Good find. However, my example is more succinct, and asks a more general question. I'm not sure if it's worth marking as a duplicate (though you and anyone else can certainly flag and vote to close as a duplicate if you feel differently.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run a Python script it automatically assumes the name `__main__`. At the time you imported `a.py` in `b.py` Python assumed the usual module name (i.e. the name of the file), and at runtime Python changed to `__main__` because it's the entry point script; so, it's like the `Foo` class was declared in two different places: the `__main__` module and the `a` module.

You're then comparing an instance of `a.Foo` (created inside `get_foo_indirectly`) and `__main__.Foo`.

This was already discussed [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-September/586708.html).

If you need to do circular imports, don't put the entry point script in the loop. This way you avoid this --very consusing-- behaviour of Python.

Comment: By don't put the "entry point script in the loop", do you mean use a separate module like my `c.py` example?

Comment: @Graham Yes! The entry point module is the module you call in the terminal, the one with `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Answer (score 4):

I've ran the same script, what I found is that you can add some line to expose some interesting differences:

```
from b import get_foo_indirectly

class Foo:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Indirect:", isinstance(get_foo_indirectly(), Foo))
    print(type(get_foo_indirectly()))
    print("Direct:", isinstance(Foo(), Foo))
    print(type(Foo()))
```

Output:

```
Indirect: False
<class 'a.Foo'>
Direct: True
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Now, for your `c.py` example, both are `a.Foo`, so they evaluate to the same. What it seem to infer here is that objects are also traced to the file/module path they come from.

This is an important distinction that act beyond the calling of `__main__`, (Which assign path as `__main__`, instead of current path from `PATH`, @Gabriel, @ehacinom). Assuming you have the exact same class defined in different files, for example, `d.py`:

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

And you try to import them to the same class `e.py`:

```
from a import Foo
from d import Foo as Fooo

print(type(Foo()))
print(type(Fooo()))
```

You'll get:

```
<class 'a.Foo'>
<class 'd.Foo'>
```

This is how python namespace classes. Moreover, if you move `d.py` to directory `/d` with `__init__.py` within the directory, and the class would become

```
<class 'd.d.Foo'>
```

All path are relative to the python `PATH`. The modules installed in `site_packages` would be available on `PATH`, and `type` would return the path of objects starting from base directory, etc:

```
<class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing an import within `__main__` must change where the class is namespaced.

`__name__` is a built-in variable which evaluates to the name of the current module. You're overwritting the special variable `__name__ == __main__` at the end of the `a.py` file, and importing `Foo` within that context.

If you print off `Foo()` in `a.py __main__()` you get `__main__.Foo instance`

If you print off `Foo()` in `b.py get_foo_indirectly()` you get `a.Foo instance`

Because of the circular import, in `b.py` you import `Foo` within the function, which is called in `__main__`. A similar thing happens if you define a class in a terminal -- it gets namespaced to `__console__`.